# Ruby - Next if vs Next unless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

What is the difference between `next if` vs `next unless`.

My understanding of `next if` was that `next only if variable == value` but in the following code, the second next statement isn't working. `next if datastore.id == 5` it is bypassing this and proceeding even if the `datastore.id == 2` or `datastore.id == 3` etc.,

```
$evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Vmware_InfraManager_Storage).all.each do |datastore|
  next if datastore.ems_id == provider.id.to_s
  next if datastore.id == 5
  dialog_hash[datastore[:id]] = "#{datastore.name} on #{datastore.ext_management_system.name}"
end
```

But if I change the `next if` to `next unless` then it works fine.

```
$evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Vmware_InfraManager_Storage).all.each do |datastore|
  next if datastore.ems_id == provider.id.to_s        # Next if works here
  next unless datastore.id == 5                       # Next unless works here instead of next if
  dialog_hash[datastore[:id]] = "#{datastore.name} on #{datastore.ext_management_system.name}"
end
```

Comment: Please make sure to construct a [mre]. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines of code.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see.

Comment: In your case, the problem is not reproducible, since we are getting totally different errors than you get, because `$evm`, `vmdb`, `dialog_hash`, `ems_id`, `ext_management`, `name`, etc. are all undefined. https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll quickly explain `next` and the difference between `if` and `unless` in ruby, and proceed to suggest some things you could try to get your code to work.

### if

Code would execute if the condition is true.

### unless

Code would execute if the condition is false. It would work the same as:

```rb
if !(expression) { ... }
```

### next

The program would skip the rest of the code inside the loop block, and skip to the next iteration.

In your case, if there is a `next` called in the first line, then the rest of the code wouldn't run.

```rb
$evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Vmware_InfraManager_Storage).all.each do |datastore|
  next if datastore.ems_id == provider.id.to_s  # if this condition is true, don't run rest of the code in this loop, and go to the next datastore
  next if datastore.id == 5 
  dialog_hash[datastore[:id]] = "#{datastore.name} on #{datastore.ext_management_system.name}"
end
```

### Suggestion

It's unclear from your question what you mean by `if` doesn't work but `unless` does.

From the first code snippet in the question, the last line of the code. i.e,

```rb
dialog_hash[datastore[:id]] = "#{datastore.name} on #{datastore.ext_management_system.name}"
```

would only run if both of the conditions above are `false`.

You can check where the data is unexpected, or if your initial conditions are wrong, by debugging the `datastore` with either a debugger or some `puts` statements inside the loop.

All the best.

Answer (score 3):

Additionally to answers, most popular Ruby style guide [recommends](https://rubystyle.guide/#unless-for-negatives) to use positive instead of negative conditions

```rb
# bad
do_something if !some_condition

# good
do_something unless some_condition
```

Depending on this, you can choose `if` or `unless`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that

- `next if condition` calls `next` when the `condition` is `true`, but
- `next unless condition` calls `next` when the `condition` is `false`.

When calling `next` with a condition like `datastore.id == 5` doesn't work as expected, then the problem is not the usage of `if` or `unless` because they work the opposite way.

Instead, you need to debug why you expect `datastore.id == 5` to be `true` and why it is not. Obviously, the condition `datastore.id == 5` can only be `true` when `datastore.id` returns the integer `5`. If it returns `false` then `datastore.id` might return a string with the digit `"5"`.

I suggest adding debug output to your code to dig deeper, like this:

```
p datastore.id
p datastore.id.class
```